# ERROR: (wheel).whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, bazel

I'm trying to build Tensorflow from source (if I install directly it works fine but I'm trying to get AVX2/FMA extensions support as I can't use CUDA/GPU) and I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@thomaschou_9652/customized-tensorflow-for-macos-1fe31110d92c) to build Tensorflow 1.15 (which is needed for the project that I use, I can't use 2.x).

I've built Tensorflow successfully, but when I try to install the wheel with pip I get the following error:

`ERROR: tensorflow-1.15.5-cp37-cp37m-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Well, I know what the error means but the problem is that:

The wheel, as implied by the filename, is built for:

- Python 3.7
- macOS 11.0
- x86/64

Which is already what I have (yup, double checked Python version, it's exactly `Python 3.7.9`, and no I'm *not* on M1 if that matters, I'm on Intel Mac). Why am I getting this error message even though I'm on the platform that the wheel is built for?

**UPDATE:** I'm already on the latest `pip` as of writing, and I can verify `pip` and `python` point to the same version:

```
(tf) can@can-mbp tensorflow % which pip 
/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/bin/pip
(tf) can@can-mbp tensorflow % which python
/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/bin/python
(tf) can@can-mbp tensorflow % pip -V
pip 21.0 from /opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
(tf) can@can-mbp tensorflow % python -V
Python 3.7.9
```

Comment: Try upgrading your `pip` version. I believe older versions have a bug with newer versions of mac os

Comment: @jordanm I'm already on the latest version, 21.0 as of writing.

Comment: How are you using `pip`? Are you using `pip install <whl>` or `python -m pip <whl>`? And  have you verified that the `pip` you are using is pointing to the python3.7 that you have indicated?

Comment: @C.Nivs I've tried both ways, same error. I've also checked that they point to the same installation from the Anaconda environment that I'm in. see the updated question.

Comment: What does simply running the `python` command give you? As in `Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24)`, etc..

Comment: @Axe319 it prints `Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 07:22:35) [Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin`

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/46 ? There are some workarounds mentioned but I'm not on Mac so I can't test.

Comment: @Axe319 unbelievable. it worked. you can post this as an answer so i can accept it when available.

Comment: You can self answer when it's available to you if you want. I'm sure you can provide more details than I could since I don't actually use Mac. I just dug through the `pip` source a bit to see what would throw the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon @Axe319's comment I took a look at https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/46 and seen that simply changing the wheel's filename's OS section to `10_9` works. There is probably a bug with parsing macOS 11.0 or Python doesn't think it supports 11.0 (maybe that particular Python/pip version was before Big Sur was released).

Answer (score 11):

FOR MACOS - BIG SUR

I was able to solve this problem when I found that the version of the **macOS operating system does not match the version actually recognized by python**

I'm using macOS 11.4, the file is with this version. But when typing a command in the terminal, I found that python recognizes 11.0.

```
python3
from distutils import util
util.get_platform()
>> 'macosx-11.0-arm64'
```

generated file name:

> opencv_python-4.5.2+2344814-cp39-cp39-**macosx_11_4_arm64**.whl

new file name:

> opencv_python-4.5.2+2344814-cp39-cp39-**macosx_11_0_arm64**.whl

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Python version you are using (32/64 bit) does match what the wheel requires ;)