# pybind .WHL file is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pybind11

I am build a .whl package on my MacOS Ventura13.4 (x86_64 platform)

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
pip install dist/my_file.whl
```

Error text:

> *.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

How to fix the error?

My versions:

```
python3.7.0 (need this version)
pip 23.1.2
pybind 2.9.1 (need this version)
setuptools 39.0.1
wheel 0.40.0
```

Python was installed from official site: (macOS 64-bit installer)

**Update**
Found out that the problem deals with `python3.7.0`, because there are no errors for `python 3.8`

What is wrong with `python3.7` ?

Comment: What is the name of the `.whl` file?. It matters. See the PEP 427 [file name convention](https://peps.python.org/pep-0427/#file-name-convention). Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645540/how-to-interpret-naming-convention-in-pypi-package-name).

Comment: wrapper-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_13_0_intel.whl

Comment: Does `python -m pip install dist/wrapper-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_13_0_intel.whl` give the same error?

Comment: @Axe319 yes, the same error

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the filenames OS version to 13_4
E.g. `wrapper-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_13_4_intel.whl`

instead of `wrapper-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_13_0_intel.whl`

It's possible the version of MacOS doesn't actually match the version recognised by python. See this Stackoverflow post:

[ERROR: (wheel).whl is not a supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65888506/error-wheel-whl-is-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

Comment: Renaming didn't help, still see the same error.